# STM8S: How to keep my functions from being interrupted by the delay function?

Tags: embedded, stm8

I was building a simple blink application on an STM8S.  The LED on-off interval was controlled by the delay function using the TIM4 interrupt. A button event monitor is using another external interrupt to prevent interference from the timer interrupt.

I found that the button event is not interrupted by the delay function, but the function associated with it still gets interrupted by the delay function.  It will only execute after delay() returns no matter how early I press the button.

Is there a way to bypass this? Should I enable another timer (like TIM2) to independently handle the button event? I need some insights.

The button is controlled by the code here:

```
INTERRUPT_HANDLER(EXTI_PORTE_IRQHandler, 7)
{
  /* In order to detect unexpected events during development,
     it is recommended to set a breakpoint on the following instruction.
  */
   //if the Button is pressed
   if(mode == 2)
  {
    mode = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    mode ++;
  }
}
```

main.c

```
void main(void)
{
  CLK_Config();
  GPIO_Config();
  TIM4_Config();

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
    Switch_Blink_Pattern(mode);
  }
  
}
```

The delay function is from STM's demo, using TIM4:

```
 INTERRUPT_HANDLER(TIM4_UPD_OVF_IRQHandler, 23)
 {
  /* In order to detect unexpected events during development,
     it is recommended to set a breakpoint on the following instruction.
  */
  TimingDelay_Decrement();
  /* Cleat Interrupt Pending bit */
  TIM4_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4_IT_UPDATE);

 }

void Delay(__IO uint32_t nTime)
{
  TimingDelay = nTime;

  while (TimingDelay != 0);
}

void TimingDelay_Decrement(void)
{
  if (TimingDelay != 0x00)
  {
    TimingDelay--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post the code to see what your code does.

Comment: I updated the codes.

Comment: the delay function doesn't interrupt another interrupt. even the timer4 ISR which is used as a delay counter, has a very low priority. it's priority could be pushed further down by enabling software priorities.

Comment: Well your code does not show everything. If your blinking code does a full sequence before even bothering to read that mode has changed the that's what it does.

Comment: `But I also found out that even the button event is not interrupted by the Delay function, but the Function associated with it still gets interrupted by the Delay function, it will only execute after delay() returns no matter how early I press the button.` you should describe this a little more.

Comment: @Justme that maybe is the issue, `Switch_Blink_Pattern(mode)` did not contain any codes that read mode changing, since I think the mode will be refreshed after next `while(1)` loop..... wait, the loop will only jump to next after the `delay()` as well?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Basically is there are 3 blinking modes, if I want to press the button to switch from mode 1 to mode 2 for example, mode 2 will only activated after mode 1 pattern finishes it's current sequence, not instantly switches.

Comment: The code does exactly what you wrote for each line. If it fully runs one blink round that takes many seconds then that's what it does and the next blink round is run with the new mode if it has changed.

Comment: @Justme so the solution should be 1. figure out a way to actively listen mode change in `Switch_Blink_Pattern(mode)` 2. find a way to "Blink without Delay"?

Comment: You need to switch mode as soon as button is pressed, even in a middle of a delay, right?

Comment: When your code calls `Switch_Blink_Pattern(mode);`, then function `Switch_Blink_Pattern` gets pass the the value of `mode` at the time that call happens. While inside `Switch_Blink_Pattern`, it has no idea if mode is being changed, because you only passed in the *value* of mode at the time the function was called. If you want `Switch_Blink_Pattern` to be looking at the mode variable all the time (instead of only at the instant the function gets called), then you could pass a pointer to `mode` instead.

Comment: @Morris that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You handle the button press in interrupt, but actually change pattern in main cycle. It is natural that Switch_Blink_Pattern() get interrupted by timer - this is how interrupts are designed to work. To get immediate reaction you need to call Switch_Blink_Pattern() from interrupt handler, like this:

```
INTERRUPT_HANDLER(EXTI_PORTE_IRQHandler, 7)
{
  /* In order to detect unexpected events during development,
     it is recommended to set a breakpoint on the following instruction.
  */
   //if the Button is pressed
   if(mode == 2)
  {
    mode = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    mode ++;
  }
  Switch_Blink_Pattern(mode);
}
```

Also, you need to check that EXTI interrupt have higher priority than TIM interrupt. You already have that (priority is second parameter of handler, lower number means higher priority).

Comment: meanwhile I was able to sort of achieved it using the idea from Arduino's "blink without delay" with the `millis()` function (I customized one), your answer let me better understand how interrupts actually work, thank you